# Packet tracer - why "show ip route" shows network address

Tags: routing, ipv4, packet-tracer

This is just a quick question I am wondering out of curiosity.

When I set up a network in packet tracer, why does "show IP route" show the network address (example: 199.120.5.64/27) and not the IP address assigned to the end device (example: 199.120.5.66) ?

It's probably not important, but I just want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show ip route` command shows the static routing assigned manually

If you do `show ip int brief` or `show ip interface brief` it will show to ip assigned to a the interfaces on that router.

Comment: `show ip route` shows much more than just routes which are static and manually configured. It shows all routes in the routing table.

Comment: @AlexandreAmaralBednell Thank you for your answer! This helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

`Router(config)# sh ip route`

This command refect existing route entries in devices and directly connected networks (L3 gateways) . It will show 199.120.5.64/27 subnet instead of assign specific ip beacuse routing table reflect entire subnet pointing towards gateways (next hop).

Destination forward packets will  destined to destination by taking  routing descision based on routing table and forward packet to gateways where route is pointed towards .